# Parallel reductions with complex objects

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, parallel-processing

Typically (from what I can tell) reduction operations produce a "number". This makes them easy to deal with since there isn't really any memory overhead.

However, I have something that I'm working on where I want to combine instances of a nontrivial data structure. That is, if `x` and `y` are instances of some class `C`, I have an operation that combines `x` and `y` into another object `z` of class `C`. Let's write `z=a+b` where `+` is my operation from pairs of `C` to `C` (mathematically, `+:C x C -> C`).

I already have an efficient implementation of `+`, but I'm struggling to get my memory allocations under control when doing a (parallel) reduction on a list of instances of `C`.

Are there some standard approaches or research related to this problem? In essence I want to reuse memory without reallocating as much as possible.

Comment: That's really going to depend on `C`. If we saw that, then maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you design an accumulator class `A` with operations `A += C`, `A += A`, and `A -> C` to collect results.

Then divide your list into N chunks where N >> num_cores.

Initial tasks do the bulk of the work by producing an `A` for each chunk, and you can then do a more standard parallel reduction on the `A`s, but since they're temporary objects, you can use `a1 += a2; return a1` instead of `return a1 + a2`.

Finally you convert the reduced accumulator to the desired output with `A -> C`.

Comment: Thank you. This approach gives up to a 50x speedup over the naive approach!